# Правильно ли расставлены пунктуационные знаки (запятые, тире) в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Чуть дальше от берега реки, где пышные кусты покрывали землю, стояли двое жеребцов, привязанных к деревьям, один — вороной, не двигался, высоко-высоко подняв голову, второй — дымчато-черный, щипал траву, дергая ушами от удовольствия.

Answer (score 1):

> Чуть дальше от берега реки, где пышные кусты покрывали землю, стояли
> двое жеребцов, привязанных к деревьям, один — вороной, не двигался,
> высоко-высоко подняв голову, второй — дымчато-черный, щипал траву,
> дергая ушами от удовольствия.

*Чуть дальше от берега реки, где пышные кусты покрывали землю, стояли два жеребца, привязанные к деревьям: один из них, вороной, не двигался, высоко подняв голову, а дымчато-чёрный — щипал траву, дергая ушами от удовольствия.*

Показалось, контекст-то не ясен, что *высоко-высоко* выбивается в этом повествовании (или проза *дергая ушами* не дотягивает). Посчитал, что от одного тире можно избавиться и что двух числительных будет достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо большое, так действительно лучше!

Comment: Может, *привязанн**ые***?

Comment: Да, очепятка. Не прав.